# How to create an ID field on bases of time separation in one column

Tags: r, database

I would like to separate the output from one of my modelling results into some kind of ID column. Since I have different particle tracks (n=15000) with varying nrow spacing i can not assume equal intervals within those (n_all= 1767333). My only separation indicator is the 'Time' columns which starts with '0'. --> so if another "0.000" appeared the ParticleID should be increased by one...

I tried different for-loops and if-else functions, but i was not able to do so...
I would really appreciate your help. Code example and data example below. Thanks in advance.

One of thos trys **not** working:

```
#initial seperation process
n_all <- nrow(all_trac)                                   #number of rows - 1767333 rows
n <- nrow(subset(all_trac, all_trac[,"IntTimeloc"] == 0)) #number of particles - 15806 particles
all_trac$Particle_ID <- 1:n_all

#start loop
for (j in 1:n_all)

  for (i in 1:n){

      if (all_trac$IntTimeloc[j] != 0) {

        all_trac$Particle_ID[j] = i

      }

      else

      all_trac$Particle_ID[j] = i+1

  } 

}
#end loop
```

How output should be in the end...

```
IntTimeloc  VXloc           VYloc           VZloc       Particle_ID
0.000   0.0009997907    9.038499e-04    -8.904433e-05   1
1.000   0.0009920447    9.680137e-04    -7.579094e-05   1
3.000   0.0009914209    9.718620e-04    -7.473217e-05   1
...
0.000   0.0008281278    -2.395466e-05   -1.537789e-04   2
9.000   0.0008310459    -2.691492e-05   -1.533394e-04   2
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
transform(dat,id = cumsum(c(1,diff(IntTimeloc)<0)))

 IntTimeloc        VXloc         VYloc         VZloc Particle_ID id
1          0 0.0009997907  9.038499e-04 -8.904433e-05           1  1
2          1 0.0009920447  9.680137e-04 -7.579094e-05           1  1
3          3 0.0009914209  9.718620e-04 -7.473217e-05           1  1
4          0 0.0008281278 -2.395466e-05 -1.537789e-04           2  2
5          9 0.0008310459 -2.691492e-05 -1.533394e-04           2  2
```